# I can not make the cookie is written with curl and php

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I'm in this new medium curl but I search the internet for a solution and can not find it. I'm trying to fill a remote form using curl and send data by post. the problem is that the external website has some security measures. One of those is that I need to complete the form to get the value that was generated and keep the cookie. external code page reads:

```
document.getElementById('sell_session').value = readCookie('classified_session');
```

My code is this:

```
$cookie_file = "/home/reelonhe/public_html//temp/cookie.txt";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.olx.com.ar/posting.php?categ_id=857');
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept-Language: es-es,en"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
$result1 = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

echo $error;
```

I tried the absolute path of the cookie with relative path. etc folder and nothing has permission to read and write. Do not know what else to do.

Comment: curl will just preserve all cookies in the cookiefile you specify, you shouldn't have to do anything for that to happen, but you will have to recreate the requests that allow that cookie to get sent by the server in the first place.

Comment: but the cookie is empty. do not understand why

Answer (score 0):

In your cookie file path

```
$cookie_file = "/home/reelonhe/public_html//temp/cookie.txt";
```

There seems an extra `'/'` before temp folder.

It should be

```
$cookie_file = "/home/reelonhe/public_html/temp/cookie.txt";
```

I am not sure it will solve your problem.

Comment: not. anything! i put $cookie_file = fopen("/home/reelonhe/public_html/temp/" .time(),"w"); this creates the file but is empty when I check